# MediaCapture.PrepareLowLagRecordToStorageFileAsync() throws "Class not registered" exception on HoloLens

Tags: c#, uwp, hololens

I'm currently working on a project to record audio on the HoloLens via a standard UWP application. I have used `MediaCapture.PrepareLowLagRecordToStorageFileAsync()` to do so. It works fine on PC, however, when I deploy it onto HoloLens, the application breaks with an `Exception` with the message "Class not registered".

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Edit: Adding the code that within the context of the error:

```
// Create the Media Encoding Profile we are going to use
var mediaEncodingProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateFlac(AudioEncodingQuality.High);
mediaEncodingProfile.Audio.ChannelCount = 1;
// Create the file to store the recording in
var localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var audioRecordingFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("audio.mp3", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
// Prepare for recording
mediaRecording = await mediaCapture.PrepareLowLagRecordToStorageFileAsync
(
    mediaEncodingProfile,
    audioRecordingFile 
);
// Begin recording
await mediaRecording.StartAsync();
```

Details on the exception thrown:

```
System.Exception
  HResult=0x80040154
  Message=Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at UwpMediaStream.MainPage.<dictationToggleGcp_Click>d__39.MoveNext() in D:\Users\xecli\Documents\Git\uwp-media-streaming-sample\UwpMediaStream\Pages\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 601
```

Edit: On further testing using `MediaCapture.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync()`, I seemed to have gotten the same error with the following callstack:

```
System.Exception
  HResult=0x80040154
  Message=Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at UwpMediaStream.MainPage.<dictationToggleGcp_Click>d__39.MoveNext() in D:\Users\xecli\Documents\Git\uwp-media-streaming-sample\UwpMediaStream\Pages\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 596
```

Comment: Could you point out which code throws this exception and provide the complete error message? And, the Holographic Mixed Reality Capture sample
(https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/HolographicMixedRealityCapture) shows how to capture mixed reality video by using Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture and MixedRealityCapture video/audio effect, you can try running this sample to narrow down if it's an issue with your code.

Comment: It's been quite awhile since I worked with C++ so I might not be interpreting the code correctly. However, based on what I read from it, it seems that it's using the MediaCapture object to record directly. I didn't do that as I was following this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/basic-photo-video-and-audio-capture-with-mediacapture#capture-audio

However, I'll give it a shot. In the meantime, I've updated the original post with the code that is throwing the exception.

Comment: I have tested using MediaCapture.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync() which was used int he sample and can verify the same issue exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to record audio in WMA format on HoloLens. I made some changes in the [Basic camera app sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit) to call the [`MediaEncodingProfile.CreateWma(AudioEncodingQuality)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.mediaproperties.mediaencodingprofile.createwma?view=winrt-19041#Windows_Media_MediaProperties_MediaEncodingProfile_CreateWma_Windows_Media_MediaProperties_AudioEncodingQuality_) method to record audio. And everything works as expected.

Here is the code I changed from [line 411](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit/cs/MainPage.xaml.cs#L411):

```
     var voiceFile = await _captureFolder.CreateFileAsync("SimpleVoice.wma", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

     var encodingProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateWma(AudioEncodingQuality.Auto);
     //encodingProfile.Video.Properties.Add(RotationKey, PropertyValue.CreateInt32(rotationAngle));
     //encodingProfile.Audio.ChannelCount = 1;
```

If it still cannot work after trying this solution, please feel free to feedback.